# "Cannot find modules" in ec2 instance But working locally

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I cloned my repo but while doing "node server" its throwing this error. I already tried reinstalling the packages.

I don't know if its a bug with ec2. Please somebody help me out.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './Routes/VendorSignin/VendorSignin.js'
Require stack:
- /home/ec2-user/specialo/specialo/server/server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/specialo/specialo/server/server.js:10:22)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/home/ec2-user/specialo/specialo/server/server.js' ]
```

Comment: Node can be rather fragile when it comes to different versions.  Are you using the same version in both your local and EC2 environment?

Comment: yes I am same to same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I changed all the server **folder** name from uppercase to lowercase.

For example: VendorSignin to vendor_signin

and it worked!! This is a weird bug so please always keep your server files in lowercase!!